# Cv2.addWeighted returns "'Tuple' Object is not callable" error

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, anaconda, spyder

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np
img1 = cv2.imread('3D-Matplotlib.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('mainsvmimage.png')

# add = img1 + img2
# add = cv2.add(img1, img2) # added all pixel values together
# (155, 211, 79) + 50, 170, 200 = 205, 381, 279 
# which becomes (205, 255, 255) since 255 is the max 

# add = cv2.add(img1//2, img2//2)
print(img1.shape)
print(img2.shape)

weighted = cv2.addWeighted(
    src1=np.array(img1), 
    alpha=0.6, 
    src2=np.array(img2), 
    beta=0.4,
    gamma=0)

cv2.imshow('image', weighted)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Above is the code I am using based on this tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/image-arithmetics-logic-python-opencv-tutorial/

I am getting the following error when I try to run this in my IDE:
`TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

I am running python version 3.6.4 on Windows 10 in Spyder version 3.2.8.

When I take the same code and I run it through the windows command prompt, it works, but it doesn't address the problem I am having in my IDE.

Comment: You don't need to re-cast them as `np.array()`s, they already are arrays. What is the result of the shape from the images? What about if you check `img1.dtype` and `img2.dtype`? Are they both the same shape and dtype?

Comment: I'm going to guess one or both of your images are not being read correctly. What happens when you just print the image? The `addWeighted()` code is correct. This is why a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always recommended for a question, since it will likely lead you to find the error yourself. Create an image from scratch (i.e. just define the matrix) and try the above. Can you get it to work then? E.g. if `img1 = np.array([[0]], dtype=np.uint8)` and `img2 = np.array([[255]], dtype=np.uint8)` works, then why doesn't your images? Something wrong with reading them.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I get that the images are the  same shape: `(250, 500, 4) ` and like I said, the code above works when I run the program from the command prompt, but inside the IDE, I get the `TypeError`

Comment: You just wrote that it works when you run from the command prompt but your OP does not say that, it says it hits a different error. What do you get from my example above?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds you are correct, I updated my status to say that it does work. I am still running into problem with the IDE however.